# rails devise using current_user and matching routes :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, controllers

I am having issues with devise current_user confusing my model's :id as the users :id.

routes:

```
match "/causes/:id/:slug" => "causes#show", :as => :cause, :via => 'get'
match "/causes/:id/:slug/edit" => "causes#edit", :as => :edit_cause, :via => 'get'
match "/causes/:id/:slug" => "causes#update", :via => 'put'

resources :causes, :only => [:index, :new, :create]
```

in my :causes controller:

```
before_filter :check_privileges, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :new, :update]

def check_privileges
    #when I use this code everyone can access edit, etc.
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user
end
```

and in my :causes model

```
  belongs_to :user
```

For some reason, when I use current_user at all, in this controller, it always thinks that current_user is equal to the id in /causes/:id/:slug/

I have tried putting the check privileges code in the application controller,

I have even tried assigning code like this:

```
def check_privileges
    #when I use this code no one can access edit, etc
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_path unless @user
end
```

I need help, anyone have suggestions? All I want it to do is verify the user is the current user so not everyone can edit the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is a bit confusing. IIRC devise stores the current user id in the session and does not ever get it from the url.

Seeing that this is a problem associated with privileges and rolling out your own solution. I would highly recommend an alternative.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

This works great with devise and should solve your problems

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. If I am user 1, and in cause 1 I can edit the cause, but if not, I get routed back to root.  I am still puzzled by this one.

Comment: I am still puzzle by your question. Why are you using the id from the params to set the user `@user = User.find(params[:id])`  ? Of course this would not work.

Comment: that was a typo, my apologies, im using User.find_by_id(params[:id])

Comment: still, thats not the confusing bit. The params[:id] is not a user id for the route match "/causes/:id/:slug".

Comment: I guess you are right, I solved this by comparing current_user.id to @cause.user_id and avoiding using params.  Thanks stellard.  I will post the answer soon.